# How to delete specific rows and keep the names?

Tags: r

It unlists it. So, I when I make it a dataframe again I lose the names of the diagnoses. Is there a simpler way to do this without having to make a separate list with the names? I just want to remove that one row. Subsetting doesn't work either. I get an error that the comparison is only possible for atomic and list types.

Comment: Why did you remove all the data and code from your question?

Comment: I was informed to redact data and change it for data integrity concerns. Using the exact file names was too much so I'm going back and will add new redacted data all over again.

Comment: You can always create mockup data or use data that comes with common packages—lots of suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862). Right now it's impossible to know what the question is, since there's no code, data, or output

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is because by default the `data.frame`, `drop = TRUE`, so it drops the dimensions when there is a single row/column to return a vector.  We can specify `drop = FALSE` (It won't happen if the object is `tibble` or `data.table`)

```
DiagnosesCount2[-c(31),, drop = FALSE]
```